# Laravel Is There A Better Way To Write My DB Query, Maybe Conditional Clause

Tags: database, laravel

I have a classified ad project where users can make Posts.  I have a 'Post' model that has a city, category and sub category.  When a user does a search for classified ads, the code I have written looks like the following:

```
    $posts = Post::all();

    if($city != 'uk')
    {
        $posts = $posts->where('city', $city);
    }

    if($category != 'cat')
    {      
        $posts = $posts->where('category', $category);
    }

    if($sub_category != 'all')
    {
        $posts = $posts->where(['category' => $category, 'sub_category' => $sub_category]);
    }
```

The city, category and sub category variables come from the loaded URL.

I am asking if there is a more efficient way of writing the code and getting the results?  Because if the Posts db table gets very large I will be getting a lot of results every time a user hits that URL, then filtering the results.  Also, I would like to paginate the results but cant get that to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use `$posts = Post::query();` instead of `$posts = Post::all();`. And something like `$results = $posts->get();` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how helpful to you but you can also do like this

```
 $posts = Post::query();

 $posts->when($city != 'uk', function ($q) use($city){
   $q->where('city',$city);
 });

 $posts->when($category != 'cat', function ($q) use($category){
   $q->where('category',$category);
 });

 $posts->when($sub_category != 'all', function ($q) use($sub_category,$category){
   $q->where(['category' => $category, 'sub_category' => $sub_category]);
 });

$posts = $posts->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-models. You should be able to do something like the following.

```
Post::where('city', $city);
```

This will push the filtering into the SQL database itself instead of filtering it in memory. You should also look up how to add indexes to tables using your sql dialect.